# Trouble feeding data into tensorflow graph

Tags: python, tensorflow, mnist

I have trained a neural network model on `MNIST` dataset using the script `mnist_3.1_convolutional_bigger_dropout.py` provided in this [tutorial](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/tensorflow-without-a-phd/tree/master/tensorflow-mnist-tutorial).

I wanted to test the trained model on the custom dataset, hence I wrote a small script `predict.py` which loads the trained model and feed the data to it. I tried 2 methods for preprocessing images so that they are compatible with MNIST format.

- **Method 1**: Resizing the image to 28x28
- **Method 2**: Technique mentioned [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=oYndcjlzwX8) is used

Both of these methods result in the error

> InvalidArgumentError (see above for traceback): You must feed a value for placeholder tensor 'Placeholder_2' with dtype float

**predict.py**

```
# Importing libraries
from scipy.misc import imread
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np
import cv2 as cv
import glob

from test import imageprepare

files = glob.glob('data2/*.*')
#print(files)

# Method 1
'''
img_data = []
for fl in files:
    img = imageprepare(fl)
    img = img.reshape(img.shape[0], img.shape[1], 1)
    img_data.append(img)
'''

# Method 2
dig_cont = [cv.imread(fl, 0) for fl in files]
#print(len(dig_cont))

img_data = []
for i in range(len(dig_cont)):
    img = cv.resize(dig_cont[i], (28, 28))
    img = img.reshape(img.shape[0], img.shape[1], 1)
    img_data.append(img)


print("Restoring Model ...")

sess = tf.Session()

# Step-1: Recreate the network graph. At this step only graph is created.
tf_saver = tf.train.import_meta_graph('model/model.meta')

# Step-2: Now let's load the weights saved using the restore method.
tf_saver.restore(sess, tf.train.latest_checkpoint('model'))

print("Model restored")

x = tf.get_default_graph().get_tensor_by_name('X:0')
print('x :', x.shape)
y = tf.get_default_graph().get_tensor_by_name('Y:0')
print('y :', y.shape)

dict_data = {x: img_data}

result = sess.run(y, feed_dict=dict_data)
print(result)
print(result.shape)

sess.close()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is fixed, I forgot to pass the value of variable `pkeep`. I had to make the following changes to make it work.

```
dict_data = {x: img_data, pkeep: 1.0}
```

instead of

```
dict_data = {x: img_data}
```